# <img /> scale to closest fit aspect ratio

Tags: javascript

I want to make the logo (in the top left corner) always keep its aspect ratio, but I also want it to stay in the right place, for *any* browser. Here's my code:

```
<body>
<img src="/home/istom/Dropbox/bcs logo border.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="position:absolute;top:6%;left:9.7%;z-index:1" />
<div style="position:absolute;top:12.5%;left:12.5%;width:75%;height:75%;border-style:solid;border-color:#6699cc;border-width:3px;background-image:url('/home/istom/Downloads/BCHands.jpg');background-position:95% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:60% auto;">
    <div style="float:left;position:relative;top:25%;left:5%;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

If you use this code, and resize your window, you'll see the logo is stretched infuriatingly out of shape. How can I make sure it keeps it's aspect ratio?

PS: If anyone can tell me how to do the same for the background-image that would great.
PS: As little jQuery as possible (still, if jQuery is the only way...)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify only the width of the image, the height will automatically be adjusted to keep the aspect ratio (and vica-versa). So remove the CSS height declarations, or the width declarations, depending on what should determine the size.

---

If you wanted to change which dimension is the deciding dimension based on the browsers aspect ratio, then you can use some JavaScript/jQuery to check. EG, tall skinny windows should have the width as the deciding dimension, and height should be used for wide short windows.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() / $(window).height() < idealWidthHeightRatio)
        $("#the_img").css({width: "auto", height: "25%"})
    else
        $("#the_img").css({width: "25%", height: "auto"})

})
```

I think I got the css syntax correct, and the width/height would have to be defined using css, not attributes.

Answer (score 1):

only give it a width ***or*** height and it will keep its aspect ratio.